# VBA, Choose specific columns instead of EntireRow.Copy

Tags: excel, vba

I have this in my code:

```
   If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then rngCopy.EntireRow.Copy _
         Sheets("Error Log").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

I want to replace `EntireRow` with different multiple columns. But I cannot do A:D. I may want A and C only. So instead of copying from EntireRow I want to copy Part of the entire row.

Comment: `Intersect(rngCopy.EntireRow, Range("A:A"),Range("C:C")).Copy`

Comment: @ScottCraner Im getting error  `Object Varaible or With block variable not set` at this line:        `If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then Intersect(rngCopy.EntireRow, Range("A:A"), Range("C:C"), Range("F:F"), Range("H:H")).Copy _
         Sheets("Error Log").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`

Comment: If rngcopy has a worksheet assigned then you will need to assign the worksheet to the Range object also.  ie `Worksheet("sheet1").Range("A:A")`

Comment: If `Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = rngCopy.Worksheet`, then for a single or adjacent multiple columns use `Intersect(rngCopy.EntireRow, ws.Columns("A:D")).Copy`. For non-contiguous columns use `Intersect(rngCopy.EntireRow, Union(ws.Columns("A"), ws.Columns("C:D"))).Copy` or shorter `Intersect(rngCopy.EntireRow, ws.Range("A:A", "C:D")).Copy`

Comment: `Intersect(rngCopy.EntireRow, rngCopy.Parent.Range("A:A,C:C")).Copy` So, does my code (from previous question) work as you need?

Comment: And the previous answer does not?

Comment: `rngCopy.entirerow.range("B1,D1,F1,H1:J1").copy` for example.  `Range()` is relative to the object it's called on.